# Is there a way to tell Sphinx to NOT run module without disabling autdoc?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, pytest

Is there a way to tell Sphinx to NOT run setup_test without disabling autdoc? 
Here's my python code:

```
def setup_test():
   ......get some stuff done here....
   return path, test

path, test = setup_test()

@pytest.mark.parametrize('asd', path, ids=test)
def test_dsf(asd):
   runpath = os.path.dirname(asd)
   assert runpath
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import sys
if 'sphinx' not in sys.modules:
    path, test = setup_test()
```

And then protect tests that use `path` and `test`

```
if 'sphinx' not in sys.modules:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize('asd', path, ids=test)
    def test_dsf(asd):
       runpath = os.path.dirname(asd)
       assert runpath
```

Or assign fake values so that Sphinx imports the module

```
if 'sphinx' in sys.modules:
    path, test = '/', 'test'
else:
    path, test = setup_test()
```

Comment: Thanks for giving a go at my question. I am not sure if this solves my issue as I am unable to run 'make html'  -  it's giving me error:        'NameError: name 'path' is not defined` in line 8 of my snippet when I run "make html"

Comment: thanks once again, this solves the error messages I get while running 'make html'. However the generated .html file fails to print the source code of test_dsf.                                                                                                                      Doesn't SPHINX support calling outside the function?                                             Is there anything I am missing in .rst file                                                          The intent behind asking this question was to ensure setup_test() does not run on the host machine when I trigger 'make html'

Comment: Sphinx extracts docstrings; it does not "print the source code". What do you mean by that?

Comment: @nss Sphinx doesn't execute code (doesn't run code **inside** functions), it **imports** modules, extracts docstrings and type annotations.

Comment: @mzjn I was actually referring to extractinng docstrings when I said printing source code.

Comment: @phd thanks, I was able to assign fake values & extract docstrings